# Use DriverManager with Tomcat connection pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Here is a code snippet using Tomcat's builtin pooling mechanism.

```
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");
p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
p.setUsername("root");
p.setPassword("password");
DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
Connection con = null;
try {
   con = datasource.getConnection();
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user");
   int cnt = 1;
   while (rs.next()) {
       System.out.println((cnt++)+". Host:" +rs.getString("Host")+
       " User:"+rs.getString("User")+" Password:"+rs.getString("Password"));
   }
   rs.close();
   st.close();
} finally {
   if (con!=null) try {con.close();}catch (Exception ignore) {}
}
```

How would I do this without using DataSource but a DriverManager?

Comment: FYI: Datasource is preferred, but I would like to know if it's possible with DriverManager

Comment: Why don't use DriverManager.getConnection method directly? There are three overloaded methods. Please look at the API. You will not have the advantages of connection pool though.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)

Comment: commons-dbcp has an example http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDriverExample.java?view=log (which is outdated) but it uses driver manager for connection pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to do the same with DriverManager. 
In fact, it's why they came up with the improved DataSource class in JDBC 2.0.

To use connection pooling with DriverManager, we have 3 options

1. Write your own implementation. More details [here](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/01/jdbc-connection-pooling-traditional.html).
2. Use a framework/library like apache-commons-dbcp. More details [here](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/01/jdbc-connection-pooling-framework.html).
3. Use the container provided DataSource. Sample [here](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/01/jdbc-connection-pooling-container.html) (based on tomcat container).